# Vue filtered list also orderBy something afterwards?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following `computed` property :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      search : '',
      users : [{name : "John Doe", email : "xerox@hotmail.us"}, {name : "Jane Doe"}],
    }
  },
  computed : {
    filteredUsers() {
      if (!this.search) return this.users

      var find =  function(object, search) {
        for (var property in object) {
          if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof object[property] == "object"){
              find(object[property]);
            } else if (object[property].includes !== undefined){
              if (object[property].includes(search)) return true;
            }
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      return this.users.filter(user => {
        return find(user, this.search)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

What can I do to order this ones by their `name`?

I do some filtering now in a `computed` property, but before I didn't do that and just used this function to do the ordering:

```
orderedList() {
   return _.orderBy(this.users, 'name')
},
```

How can I **combine** the two functions or add the `orderBy` part to the filteredUsers function?

Comment: you need a method to sort your `users` by the given key (in your case is `name`)?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I want the funcion filteredUsers() to keep working,but as a result I wanna order them by their 'name'

Comment: i understand that you want to use ordered users by name in the `filteredUsers` property ? or the reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@boussadjira's answer is fine, but if you really don't want the extra function, just use the following as the return from `filteredUsers()`

```
return _.orderBy(
    this.users.filter(user => find(user, this.search)),
    'name'
);
```

(and similarly in the short-circuit return when `search` is empty)

Answer (score -1):

Using [linq](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js) js lib.

```
 computed: {
    filteredUsers {
      return Enumerable.From(this.users).OrderBy(x => x.name).ToArray();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Uhhh, that destroys the whole function?

Comment: so far, I've noticed you've written data property as a function instead of object. However, in component’s data option must be a function.